# Python: Elements in a list not being changed?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm having issues with editing elements in a list in Python, I've got the following code:

```
mylist = ["one", "day", "soon"]
for x in mylist: 
    x = "New word"
    print(x)

print(mylist)
```

I would expect the output to be "New Word" three times (once for each iteration) and then a list of ["New Word", "New Word", "New Word"], but instead I've been getting:

New word 
New word 
New word
['one', 'day', 'soon']

**Question:** Why is the list apparently changing, but then reverting back to its original form when printed as a whole list?

Note: I have fixed the issue with the following code, but I am still curious as to why the original method fails

```
mylist2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
for x in mylist2 : 
    mylist2[mylist2.index(x)] = "Woo"

print(mylist2)
```

Comment: Think of `x` as a pass-by-value copy of `mylist2`.

Comment: @intboolstring I'm not quite sure I know exactly what you mean sorry? I'm just picking up programming again after a long break, what do you mean by pass-by-value?

Comment: I'm on mobile right now so I can't type too much. Google pass-by-value vs. pass by Reference

Comment: @intboolstring that's not helpful. This is neither pass-by-value or pass-by-reference, the issue is mutation vs rebinding. Compare what happens if `mylist` is a list of lists, and `x` therefore refers to a list; if the code modifies `x[0]`, the original list *would* be affected.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not saying this is pass by value or pass by reference. I'm saying for a beginner, that is an easy way to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you iterate with `for x in mylist` and then assign a value to `x`, you are creating a new variable called `x` and that is what you are printing. You cannot change the list in that way, only by iterating like this:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = "New word"
```

Comment: Perfect, better than my solution and well explained, thank you!